# Python - convert number of hours to a date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have in Python 3.7 a date in form of an integer that represents the number of hours from 1/1/1900 00 Hours. Can I transform it into string of format dd/mm/yyyy?

for example:

```
timenumber = 1043148
timestring = magictrickfunctions(timenumber)
print(timestring)
```

should give "01/01/2017"

Comment: Multiply it by `60 * 60`, then it’s a regular UNIX time stamp…!?

Comment: Each of the steps for this is covered well elsewhere on this site and on line.  I've covered this with the critical conversion link; the rest is simple arithmetic.

Comment: No, Prune. The solution you have suggested was not functioning. The answer by AzyCrw4282 was nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it gives you `01/01/2017` instead of `01/01/2019`?

To obtain the number of days divide your total hours by `/24` this will give you the number of days. You can then specify that as shown below. I am using pandas library here.

```
import pandas as pd
start_date  = "01/01/1900"
date_1 = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
end_date = date_1 + pd.DateOffset(days=43464) #specify the number of days and add it to your start_date
print(end_date)
```

Outtput

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00
```